# Derivative of trigonometric functions python

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am working on a little side project and building a calculator for different numerical analysis methods. What I am struggling with is calculating derivatives of trigonometric functions. For calculations of derivatives I am using sympy and math Python library.

```
print(sym.diff(math.cos(x)))
```

The correct answer for this should be `-sin(x)`, however I get:

```
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Is there any way I can correctly calculate derivatives of trigonometric functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SymPy has its own functions which know how to be differentiated. `math` versions only know how to give a numerical answer for numerical input.

```
>>> from sympy import sin
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> sin(x).diff(x)
cos(x)
```

Comment: What do you know, I learn't something new today. Thanks @smichr

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea of how to go about it.

```
import sympy as sym
import math

x=sym.symbols('x') 
def f(x):
    return x**2

print(sym.diff(f(x)))
```

Comment: Please could you elaborate a little bit? I have no problem working with regular equations, its the trigonometric ones which raise an error. I tried doing it via function as you suggested, however I am still getting the same error

Comment: I don't think you can get the exact derivative of a trig function. Because calculus in a nutshell occurs because you are dividing by 0 and python can't do that.